# AngularJS: use $broadcast to hide table columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use the angularjs $broadcast property to hide my table columns. If the data is broadcasted the table column should be shown else the table column should be hidden. Currently if i run my code, once login i broadcasted my login username to the function but still my whole table is not showing. Can i know a way to solve it.

This is my controller.js code:

```
.controller('AllMovieController', 
            [
                '$scope', 
                'dataService', 
                '$location',
                '$rootScope',

                function ($scope, dataService, $location, $rootScope){
                    $scope.noteEnabled = false;
                    $scope.movies = [ ];
                    $scope.movieCount = 0;
                    $scope.currentPage = 0; //current page
                    $scope.entryLimit = 20; //max no of items to display in a page

                    var getAllMovie = function () {
                        dataService.getAllMovie().then(
                            function (response) {
                                $scope.$on("passuser", function ($event, data ){
                                    if(data){
                                        $scope.movies = response.data;
                                        $scope.showSuccessMessage = true;
                                        $scope.successMessage = "All movie Success";
                                        $scope.noteEnabled = true;
                                    }else{
                                        $scope.movies = response.data;
                                        $scope.noteEnabled = false;
                                    }
                                });


                            },
                            function (err){
                                $scope.status = 'Unable to load data ' + err;
                            }
                        );  // end of getStudents().then
                    };

                    $scope.numberOfPages = function(){
                        return Math.ceil($scope.movies.length / $scope.entryLimit);
                    };


                    getAllMovie();

                }
            ]
        )
```

This is my partial html code:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th ng-show="noteEnabled">Notes</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies | pagination: currentPage * entryLimit | 
    limitTo: entryLimit">
        <td>
            {{movie.title}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{movie.description}}
        </td>
        <td data-ng-click="selectFilmDetails($event,movie)" ng-show="noteEnabled" >
            {{movie.comment}}
        </td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is the broadcasted controller code:

```
.controller('LoginController',
            [
                '$scope',
                'dataService',
                '$location',
                '$window',
                '$rootScope',
                function ($scope, dataService, $location, $window, $rootScope){
                    $scope.check_login = function($event,userID,passwd){
                        dataService.login(userID,passwd).then(
                            function (response){
                                if(response.result.status=='ok'){
                                    $scope.user = response.user;
                                    $rootScope.$broadcast("passuser", $scope.user);
                                    $location.path('#/home');
                                    //$window.location.reload();

                                }else{
                                    $scope.message = response.result.message;

                                }
                            },

                            function (err) {
                                $scope.status = 'unable to connect to data' + err;
                            }
                        );

                    }//end of function check_login 
                }
            ]
        )
```

Previously, i used session to check whether the user is logged in, but now i am using broadcast to pass the username to the controller. And the same i tried to pass the username to this controller its not working. I really need a help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend moving your event listener outside the `.then()` of your `getAllMovie()` service call. What happens if the `passuser` event is broadcast before that promise resolves? Here's how I would recommend restructuring your code (I removed the modules you were injecting, but not using):

**Update**: The issue may be that your controller that has the event listener isn't instantiated when you are broadcasting the event. This is a guess because it's unclear if these are one view, different views, etc. I would suggest storing the logged in status in a value instead. *This is just one example - it may not be the best way or one that will address all of what you need. I haven't tested this so you may have to play around with it to get it to work the way you want.* Here is my updated recommended code:

```
.value('UserInfo', { user: '', loggedIn: false })
.controller('LoginController',
    ['$scope', 'dataService', '$location', 'UserInfo',
    function ($scope, dataService, $location, UserInfo) {
        $scope.check_login = function($event,userID,passwd) {
            dataService.login(userID,passwd).then(
                function (response){
                    if(response.result.status=='ok'){
                        UserInfo.user = response.user;
                        UserInfo.loggedIn = true;
                        $location.path('#/home');
                    } else {
                        $scope.message = response.result.message;
                        UserInfo.user = '';
                        UserInfo.loggedIn = false;
                    }
                },
                function (err) {
                    $scope.status = 'unable to connect to data' + err;
                    UserInfo.user = '';
                    UserInfo.loggedIn = false;
                });
        }//end of function check_login 
    }])
.controller('AllMovieController', ['$scope', 'dataService', 'UserInfo',
    function ($scope, dataService, UserInfo) {
        $scope.noteEnabled = false;
        $scope.movies = [];
        $scope.movieCount = 0;
        $scope.currentPage = 0; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 20; //max no of items to display in a page

        $scope.noteEnabled = UserInfo.loggedIn;

        var getAllMovie = function () {
            dataService.getAllMovie().then(
                function (response) {
                    $scope.movies = response.data;
                    $scope.showSuccessMessage = true;
                    $scope.successMessage = "All movie Success";
                },
                function (err) {
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to load data ' + err;
                });
        };

        $scope.numberOfPages = function() {
            return Math.ceil($scope.movies.length / $scope.entryLimit);
        };

        getAllMovie();
}]);
```

Comment: It's still not working for me. I tried to console log the data but i am not getting any value. Its not even going into the scope.on function

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code where you are calling `$rootScope.$broadcast()`? Have you debugged to make sure that bit of code is running?

Comment: i have added the broadcasted controller do take a look at it